# Finding Exploits in Web Apps, Apps

Tags: exploit

I've always wondered, how do Hackers manage to find exploits in web apps, apps and hardware? Do they work in a team?

Comment: There are entire books written on this subject, including one called "The Web Hackers Handbook" (http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-1118026470.html) - this doesn't really show any research effort...

Comment: This imo is a very broad question with a lot of answers. The question shows no research. You'd get much better results looking at @Matthew 's suggestion or just searching.

Answer (score 1):

This question is about as broad as "How do people make music? Do they play in a band?".  Lots of ways, and yes respectively.

For applications, you can do always do [fuzzing](https://fuzzing-project.org/tutorial1.html). If you have the binary you can do [reverse engineering](http://www.foo.be/cours/dess-20122013/b/Eldad_Eilam-Reversing__Secrets_of_Reverse_Engineering-Wiley(2005).pdf), and if you have the source you can do [source code analysis](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Source_Code_Analysis_Tools). All of which are quite complex. People do do this in teams, for CTF challenges and companies for example. But it's quite doable on your own.